# How to add css to specific blocks or view with CSS injector module?

Tags: theming

**How to add css to specific blocks or view with CSS injector module?**

I can add css to specific pages, but what about blocks, views and all sorts of other nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am try already this but i think it would be helpfull

Use php section to add css against any view or block
and try this one

```
<?php
if ( $block->module == 'your_block_id/name'){
          //add some code here
}
?>
```

Or can do it by add a class in view or block

Answer (score -1):

Using the [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) module, there is not a way to only add CSS to **pages that include specific elements** such as Views, blocks, etc.

However, that's generally OK. If you're using Drupal's built-in CSS aggregation (and/or [Advanced Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg)), you're really just looking at couple hundred bytes per page, which *should* be cached by the browser, making those tweaks fairly negligible in terms of page load times.

Comment: Sorry but I dont' understand that answer at all...so this CAN'T be done?